# Pass base64 image from php query to html5 canvas

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

I'm getting a base64 string from the database with a query in PHP. This string represents an image.

I want to display this image in the html5 canvas, but it just won't work.

The string is stored in $DBimage. I then use:

```
var complex = <?php echo ($DBimage); ?>;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
image.src = "data:image/  png;base64, document.write(complex)";
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: dont edit answer to show the result instead comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 is still a string, so you need to quote it. Also, you're using document.write in a string? I'm assuming your trying to append it.

```
var complex = "<?php echo $DBimage; ?>";
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + complex;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);}
```

**Update:**

There are newlines in `$DBImage` based on the look of [this](http://www.bartf.nl/base64/). This makes a javascript error. (New lines are not permitted in strings in Javascript), This should fix it.

```
var complex = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $DBimage); ?>";
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + complex;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: Thanks, the string now is loaded into complex, but the canvas stays empty. Is there any change the string isn't loaded yet before the page is.

Comment: PHP is all run before the page is actually sent, whereas JavaScript runs once the page has already been loaded. Can you show us more detail?

Comment: @user1786301 Maybe you need your last line to be `image.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(image, 0 ,0) }`? That ensures that `image` is ready to be drawn before `ctx.drawImage` is called.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. I did a little test. <?php $test= "\9sdfhwjef....etc">;?> Then echo $test in js, but also here the canvas stays empty.

Comment: Is `image` just an image element from `document.createElement('img')`?

Comment: And can you give us a link to where we can take a closer look?

Comment: Yes! That did the job almost. I needed to add var image = new Image();.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've got it working. Now I can focus on the next problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();

image.src = "data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...etc";
image.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

But

```
var complex = "<?php echo $DBimage; ?>";
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();

image.src = "data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...etc";
image.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

Doesn't work. So only adding the echo from php keeps the canvas from showing anything.

Comment: I now know what's going wrong. When I pass the string with the variable 'complex', the string is broken down in separate lines. I need the string to be 1 line.